# Flyback switching power supply flickering debugging and proper software for its simulation

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, switching, flyback

we are using PIExpert V6 for building one fly-back switching power supply, SO the calculated power supply is this kind:

[image]

and the Altium files is here:

[image]

source files are here:

[source files](https://ufile.io/24e)

or :

[Another link for source files](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=30789434405439680952)

So the problem is here,When we connect the **220V AC voltage source** to our power supply and connect the lamp to output,the lamp becomes **on** for only one second and then is **off**, then **on** then **off** and so on ... .
So what do you thin about this kind of operation causes and the way for fixing it.

And finally is there any professional software exist for simulating this kind of power supply before building it physically, we could not simulate this circuit in **Altium V9** because there is no **TNY280PN** and the proposed transformator , so if you have simulated this kind of circuit please guide us to the correct way.(Any idea about simulating with **MATLAB, PSPICE** or ... and examples ).

Thanks a lot for your attention .

Comment: Nobody is going to download your files. Basically you have a design based on some unknown spec (to us) and you have connected it to a load of unknown characteristics and there is some behavior that you describe that is supposedly problematic but you haven't explained what the problem is. How can anyone feasibly answer you?

Comment: Have you measured what your flyback is doing with an oscilloscope?

Comment: No, we have not any oscilloscope,yet!!!